# How can I render a list of objects using DisplayFor but from the controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, controller, render

Here's the scenaio, I have an Employee object and a Company object which has a list of employees.

I have `Company.aspx` which inherits from `ViewPage<Company>`.

In Company.aspx I call

```
Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Employees).
```

I have an `Employee.ascx` partial view which inherits from `ViewUserControl<Employee`> in my DisplayTemplates folder.

Everything works fine and `Company.aspx` renders the `Employee.ascx` partial for each employee.

Now I have two additional methods on my controller called `GetEmployees` and `GetEmployee(Id)`.

In the `GetEmployee(Id)` action I want to return the markup to display this one employee, and in `GetEmployees()` I want to render the markup to display all the employees (these two action methods will be called via AJAX).

In the GetEmployee action I call

```
return PartialView("DisplayTemplates\Employee", employee)
```

This works, although I'd prefer something like

```
return PartialViewFor(employee)
```

which would determine the view name by convention.

Anwyay, my question is how should I implement the `GetEmployees()` action?

I don't want to create any more views, because frankly, I don't see why I should have to.

I've tried the following which fails miserably :)

```
return Content(New HtmlHelper<IList<Of DebtDto>>(null, null).DisplayFor(m => debts));
```

However if I could create an instance of an HtmlHelper object in my controller, I suppose I could get it to work, but it feels wrong.

Any ideas? Have i missed something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

I've always solved this by having a Partial View which loops over an `IEnumerable<T>` and calls `Html.DisplayFor()` on each item, but then I didn't even know you could call `Html.DisplayFor()` on an `IEnumerable<T>` and have it automatically render each templated element until you said so in your question. Thanks for that, by the way! :)

In any case, I think your best bet is to simply return a `PartialView()` which accepts a collection of Employees and <strike>renders them one at a time</strike> calls `Html.DisplayFor()`. It's not as elegant as returning an HtmlHelper from your controller, but at least it's simple enough to implement.

Comment: It looking like that be what I have to do. Ideally I want to avoid creating partial views with just 1 line of code. I've been looking at make creating a new DisplayFor action result, but again, I haven't been able to get this to work. Anyway, thanks for your input, and I'm glad I was able to help you :)